# Compare with list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list `cids` that I am fetching like this

```
var cids = _service.Employee.Where(i => i.EmpID == _empID).Select(j => j.ClientID).ToList();
```

I want to compare this list with `Patient Entity` and get all the records of patients that matches the clientId in the `cid list`

Patient Entity is like this

```
class Patient   
{   
    Int PatientID{ get; set;}   
    Int ClientID{get; set;}   
    string PatientName{get; set;}
}
```

Right now I am doing it like this

```
foreach(var item in cids)
{
     var pp = from p1 in _service.Patients
                            where p1.ClientId == item
                            select new PatientDTO
                            {
                                PatientID = p1.PatientID,
                                PatientName = p1.PatientName,

                            };
     prec.Add(pp);
}
```

Is there a way to do it with `Linq` without using `foreach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Contains` on your List (you don't need the `ToList`, by the way : this would avoid 2 queries on db).

```
var allPp = _service.Patients.Where(p1 => cids.Contains(p1.ClientId))
                             .Select(m >= new PatientDTO) {
                                   PatientID = m.PatientID,
                                PatientName = m.PatientName
                             });
```

But the most performant way, in a db world, would be a join

```
from emp in _service.Employee.Where(i => i.EmpID == _empID)
join patient in _service.Patients on emp.ClientId equals patient.ClientId
select new PatientDTO {
  PatientID = patient.PatientID,
  PatientName = patient.PatientName,
}
```

Comment: +1. I don't see why this answer got negative vote. This answer directly responds to the request: the `foreach` loop was rewritten as `Where`, and the rest was left untouched. Of course `Intersect` would be (often, not always) better, but hey, this response has 100% accuracy to the actual question.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus  Thanks, your first query works great. I am getting this error with your second query `"The type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect. type inference failed in the call Join"` Can you please help

Comment: @ElectricRouge is ClientId of the same Type in Employee and Patient ? Or is one of them nullable ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus its `short` in Employee and `int` in Patient

Comment: @ElectricRouge just to be clear : did you do something like `on (int)emp.ClientId equals patient.ClientId` ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus yes I did

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus query is executing fine but I am getting `Children could not be evaluated` as result.

Comment: @ElectricRouge you get this if you do `var pp = <thequery>; var result = pp.ToList();`

Answer (score 3):

Use [Enumberable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to fetch common records.

```
var commonClients = cids.Intersect<int>(_service.Patients.Select(x => x.ClientID));

var person = _service.Patients.Where(x => commonClients.Contains(x.ClientID));
```

Comment: Providing an example rather than a link would be preferred.